# Giving positional arguments for Co-ordinates and Clustering them together

Tags: python, list, dictionary

so I have a data file and I'm wanting to find two things:

1. Whether the coordinates I give are inside or outside an area and returning if its true or not
2. Put each coordinates of "1" together in each line in its own list. This should return it in a dictionary.

The file has the following:

```
1 1 0 1 0 1
0 0 1 1 1 0
1 1 1 1 1 0
1 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 1 1 0 1
1 0 0 0 0 1
```

I've put the above into a list and each with the code:

```
lines = []
with open('area.dat', 'r') as a:
    for line in a:
        line = line.strip()
        if not line:
            continue
        lines.append(list(map(int, line.split())))
        data.extend(map(int, line.split()))


print(lines)
```

My attempts at code to get the coordinates and whether it's outside or inside the area (for both x and y)

**area is the list of lists**

```
x = int(input('enter x: '))
y = int(input('enter y: '))


def cords(x, y, area):
    if x > 6 or y > 6:
        print('Outside Area')
        return(False)
    else:
        print('Inside Area')
        return(True)
```

I want to get a coordinate x and y within the list "area" and return whether it is in or out this.

So for example if I put in cords(0,4,area) it will return "True" and if I put cords(3,7,area) it will return "False".

After this I then want to put them together in groups of 1's by each line.

so for example line 1 and 2 would give:

{1: [(0,4), (0,5)], 2: [(1,0), (1,1)]}

All help is appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part you have two options:

```
def cords(x, y):
    return x >= 0 and x < 6 and y >= 0 and y < 6
```

This first option is static for an area size of 6x6, note that array indexing starts at 0 so 6 would already be out of bounds.

```
def cords(x, y, area):
    return x >= 0 and x < len(area) and y >= 0 and y < len(area[0])
```

This second option dynamically checks whether the coordinates are in bounds of the given nested list. You might have to adjust it based on whether x and y relate to rows and columns or vice versa.

---

Now for your second part, you're creating a dictionary with redundant information, since the index (1 and 2 in your example) directly relates to the first axis (0 and 1 in your example), you might want to reconsider what you actually want to achieve here.

```
d = {}
for i,row in enumerate(lines):
    n = []
    for j,v in enumerate(row):
        if v == 1:
            n.append([i,j])
    d[i+1] = n
```